# How to update object returned in query

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

So I'm a flask/sqlalchemy newbie but this seems like it should be a pretty simple. Yet for the life of me I can't get it to work and I can't find any documentation for this anywhere online. I have a somewhat complex query I run that returns me a list of database objects.

```
items = db.session.query(X, func.count(Y.x_id).label('total')).filter(X.size >= size).outerjoin(Y, X.x_id == Y.x_id).group_by(X.x_id).order_by('total ASC')\
    .limit(20).all()
```

after I get this list of items I want to loop through the list and for each item update some property on it.

```
for it in items:
   it.some_property = 'xyz'
   db.session.commit()
```

However what's happening is that I'm getting an error

```
it.some_property = 'xyz'
AttributeError: 'result' object has no attribute 'some_property'
```

I'm not crazy. I'm positive that the property does exist on model X which is subclassed from db.Model. Something about the query is preventing me from accessing the attributes even though I can clearly see they exist in the debugger. Any help would be appreciated.

```
class X(db.Model):
    x_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    size = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    oords = db.relationship('Oords', lazy=True, backref=db.backref('x', lazy='joined'))

    def __init__(self, capacity):
        self.size = size
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your example your **result objects** do not have the attribute `some_property`, just like the exception says. (Neither do model `X` objects, but I hope that's just an error in the example.)

They have the explicitly labeled `total` as second column and the model `X` instance as the first column. If you mean to access a property of the `X` instance, access that first from the result row, either using index, or the implicit label *X*:

```
items = db.session.query(X, func.count(Y.x_id).label('total')).\
    filter(X.size >= size).\
    outerjoin(Y, X.x_id == Y.x_id).\
    group_by(X.x_id).\
    order_by('total ASC').\
    limit(20).\
    all()

# Unpack a result object
for x, total in items:
   x.some_property = 'xyz'

# Please commit after *all* the changes.
db.session.commit()
```

As noted in the other answer you could use [bulk operations](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.update) as well, though your `limit(20)` will make that a lot more challenging.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: Fixed overwriting the class variable with the instances in the for-loop. A left over from first thinking of writing `it.X`, but then going with unpacking.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the update function.

Like that:

```
from sqlalchemy import update

stmt = update(users).where(users.c.id==5).\
        values(name='user #5')
```

Or :

```
session = self.db.get_session()
session.query(Organisation).filter_by(id_organisation = organisation.id_organisation).\
update(
    {
        "name" : organisation.name,
        "type" : organisation.type,
    }, synchronize_session = False)
session.commit();
session.close()
```

The sqlAlchemy doc : http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/dml.html